# Simple Commerce tag in Standard Channel entries tag?

Tags: simple-commerce

I am looking to use simple commerce price variable inside a standard channel entries tag.  Using the following code, it is not parsing the {item_regular_price} and simply displaying the tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="membership_packages" dynamic="no"}
  <li><a href="{page_url}">{title} - {item_regular_price}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the information from  the simple commerce item to display in channel entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, you need to wrap the simple commerce tags with in the simple commerce purchase tags like so...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="membership_packages" dynamic="no"}
     <li><a href="{page_url}">{title} - {exp:simple_commerce:purchase entry_id="{entry_id}" success="site/success" cancel="site/index"} {item_regular_price}{/exp:simple_commerce:purchase}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It's important to note that the "success" and "cancel" parameters are required and it will not work without them.